# SDL android app crashes when interacting with touchscreen

Tags: android, java-native-interface, sdl

I am trying to develop games for android using the SDL library. The app itself starts
perfectly and you are able to use everything except the touchscreen. If the touchscreen
is interacted with the app crashes leaving the following message in the logcat:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000030 (code=1), thread 868 (org.libsdl.app)
```

If i comment out the SDLActivity.onNativeTouch calls the app doesn't crash but i am
not able to utilize the touchscreen information, which is needed.

I am using the SDL android example app which have been cloned from http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL

During the setup of this app i have been following this guide:

http://www.dinomage.com/2013/01/howto-sdl-on-android/

I have tested the app on a physical device and a emulator 
which both produced the same results.

Does anyone have any ideas on what the problem might be?

Comment: A full stack trace and the code snip-it that is causing the segfault would be beneficial.

Comment: This was a bug on recent revisions (not releases!) of SDL. It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by switching to an older release. In the guide i was following they used the SDL 2.0.0 release i assume and the one that i used were SDL 2.0.3. So by switching to an older release the touchscreen works as intended.